# Play-Slick plugin, throws abstraction error in case of DateTime variables, data types

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick-2.0, play-slick

I have been using slick 2 as the dbms for my play app, though using play-slick plugin rather then slick independently, and added the tototoshi plugins as well, dependencies are:

```
"joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.4"
"org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.6"
"com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "1.2.0"
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.6.1"
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.3"
```

And the case class and projection are :

//Slick imports used

```
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
import play.api.db.slick.DB
import scala.slick.lifted.ProvenShape
import com.github.tototoshi.slick.MySQLJodaSupport._

case class Design(
var id: Int,
var imageName: String,
var title: String,
var creatorID: Int,
var flagged: Boolean,
var modifiedTimestamp: Instant,
var createdTimestamp: Instant) {
def this() = this(0, "", "", 0, false, DateTime.now.toInstant, DateTime.now.toInstant)
}

class DesignProjection(tag: Tag) extends Table[Design](tag, "designs_47") {
def id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
def imageName: Column[String] = column[String]("des_image_name")
def title: Column[String] = column[String]("des_title")
def creatorID: Column[Int] = column[Int]("des_creator_id")
def flagged: Column[Boolean] = column[Boolean]("des_flagged_link")
def modifiedTimestamp: Column[Instant] = column[Instant]("tt_modified_timestamp")
def createdTimestamp: Column[Instant] = column[Instant]("tt_tweeted_timestamp")

def * : ProvenShape[Design] = (id, imageName, title, creatorID, flagged, modifiedTimestamp, createdTimestamp) <> (
((Design.apply _): (Int, String, String, Int, Boolean, Instant, Instant) => Design).tupled,
Design.unapply)

}
```

And when I try to list all rows using method :

```
def list: List[Design] = {
println("Start Listing")
val result = DB.withSession { implicit session =>
val res = designProjection.list <-error here
res
}
convertListResultSet(result)
}
```

I get `[RuntimeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError]`, well I am more then sure its cause of the DataTime class, but I really don't know whats going wrong. I have used the tototoshi plugins as well. All other cases where DateTime are considered, they are working fine.

Any help or pointers are really welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue.
https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper/issues/19

Could you try slick-joda-mapper 1.1.0 ?

Comment: Ya, it did work, should have properly checked the dependency infos.